# Data Transfer through RTSP in Gstreamer

Tags: gstreamer

**UPDATE::**

I want to stream video data (H264) through RTSP in Gstreamer.

```
 gst_rtsp_media_factory_set_launch (factory, "videotestsrc ! x264enc ! rtph264pay name=pay0 pt=96 ");
```

I want "videotestsrc ! x264enc ! rtph264pay name=pay0 pt=96" this pipeline would also be in C programming in place of direct command.

Actually I have custom pipeline, i want to pass this pipeline to GstRTSPMediaFactory.

With launch i am not able to pass my pipline.

```
source = gst_element_factory_make("videotestsrc", "test-source");
parse = gst_element_factory_make("x264enc", "parse");
sink = gst_element_factory_make("rtph264pay", "sink");
gst_bin_add_many(GST_BIN(pipeline), source, parse, sink, NULL);
gst_element_link_many(source, parse, sink, NULL);
```

Now, I want to stream this pipeline using RTSP. I can stream with gst_rtsp_media_factory_set_launch,

But i want to pass only pipeline variable, and has to stream the video.

Can it possible, if so How?

I Modified the rtsp-media-factory.c as follows,

```
Added GstElement *pipeline in struct _GstRTSPMediaFactoryPrivate.
```

And the Added two more functions get_pipeline & set pipeline

```
void
gst_rtsp_media_factory_set_launch_pipeline (GstRTSPMediaFactory * factory, GstElement *pipeline)
{
  g_print("PRASANTH :: SET LAUNCH PIPELINE\n");
  GstRTSPMediaFactoryPrivate *priv;
  g_return_if_fail (GST_IS_RTSP_MEDIA_FACTORY (factory));
  g_return_if_fail (pipeline != NULL);
  priv = factory->priv;
  GST_RTSP_MEDIA_FACTORY_LOCK (factory);
//  g_free (priv->launch);
  priv->pipeline = pipeline;
  Bin = priv->pipeline;
  GST_RTSP_MEDIA_FACTORY_UNLOCK (factory); 

}
```

In the Same way get also.

And at last in place of gst_parse_launch in function default_create_element,

added this line

```
element = priv->pipeline; // priv is of type GstRTSPMediaFactoryPrivate
return element;
```

but I am not able to receive the data.
When i put pay0 for rtpmp2pay it is working.

But it is working for once only. If Client stops and again starts its not working. To work it, again i am restarting the server.

What is the problem?

```
** (rtsp_server:4292): CRITICAL **: gst_rtsp_media_new: assertion 'GST_IS_ELEMENT (element)' failed
```

Comment: I do not understand the sentence "I want.." - you want to test it in non rtsp C code? Or are you asking about the rest of the C gstreamer RTSP code to make it work? I guess you are following [this](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-rtsp-server/tree/docs/README?h=1.6#n152) if not its useful..

Comment: please check the question once, i updated it.

If you know the answer, please help me.

Comment: ok now I understand and I do not know the answer.. it seems that the only way is through _set_launch, otherwise you have to subclass the GstRTSPMediaFactory as stated [here](http://gstreamer-devel.966125.n4.nabble.com/passing-pipeline-to-GstRTSPMediaFactory-td3317873.html)

Comment: To overcome this i modified rtsp-media-factory.c.
in its structure i add a GstElement *pipeline; variable,
and i assigned my pipeline to it by calling a function set_pipeline.

But the problem is it is not able to send data, when i passing the pipeline = gst_pipeline_new("p");

but It is able to send data when i passing pipeline = gst_parse_launch.

What is the difference between these two as i asked here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34042082/is-gst-parse-launch-return-type-and-pipeline-are-same)

Comment: ok then add details on how you modified the source - but please do not create another question.. just edit this one with caption *UPDATE* .. you should also merge the information from [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34042082/is-gst-parse-launch-return-type-and-pipeline-are-same) question into this one and close the other question.. you are making it hard for people to answer your questions when you split the information through multiple questions

Comment: check it the updated question

Comment: what happens when you put proper name for `sink = gst_element_factory_make("rtph264pay", "pay0");` - the GstRTSPMediaFactory is counting on fact that the payloader will be named by payXY..

Comment: Yeah. Its Working. Thanks for that. But the problem is,

when i stop the rtspclient in between streaming, and again if i start the client it is giving critical errors

I Updated the question. Please check it once

Comment: does stopping client work for _parse version?

Comment: it is working for _parse. But it is not working for the pipeline which i am passing.

I am not able to find where it is storing and reusing the data.

If you can please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have some answer here.
It solves the main problem according to comments discussion, but there is still problem with requesting another stream (when stopping and starting client).

The solution was to add proper name for payloader element as stated in [docs](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-rtsp-server/tree/docs/README?h=1.6#n135):

> The pipeline description should contain elements named payN, one for each
>    stream (ex. pay0, pay1, ...). Also, for increased compatibility each stream
>    should have a different payload type which can be configured on the payloader.

So this has to be changed to:

```
sink = gst_element_factory_make("rtph264pay", "pay0");
```

notice the change in name of element from sink -> pay0.

For the stopping client issue I would check if this works for parse version.
If yes then check if the parse pipeline string (in original source code of rtsp server) is saved anywhere and reused after restart.. you need to debug this.

Comment: Yeah, thats correct. but if i want to stream video, by passing only the pipeline variable.

If u don't mind, i updated the question, please check it once.